# WSO2 Api Manager url context

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am version 3.2.0 and trying to configure reverse proxy using NginX following the below mentioned documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/

I want to access the devportal and publisher with a new url context like https://{domain-name}/wso2am/devportal and https://{domain-name}/wso2am/publisher. My nginx configuration file is as below.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  {domain-name};
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/{cert_name};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/{key_name};

         location /wso2am/ {
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_read_timeout 5m;
                    proxy_send_timeout 5m;
                    proxy_pass https://<server-ip>:9443;
                }
    
            access_log /etc/nginx/log/am/https/access.log;
            error_log /etc/nginx/log/am/https/error.log;
    }
```

with this configuration, when I try to access https://{domain-name}/wso2am/devportal it is redirected to the carbon login url (https://{domain-name}/carbon/admin/login.jsp) with a 404 not found error. Should I change any values in carbon.xml or in some other files for get this working?

Note: I tried to change the `<WebContextRoot>` in carbon.xml file with `/wso2am` as its value. When I restarted the server the value is overwritten again to the default `/`.

Where should I add the /wso2am context path in carbon configurations?

Comment: Can you try checking to rewrite the URL in Nginx? i.e rewrite /wso2/am -> / 
https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/, https://www.journaldev.com/26864/nginx-rewrite-url-rules

Comment: I tried setting proxy_redirect in the configuration file like 
`proxy_redirect https://{ip}:9443/ https://{ip}:9443/wso2am/`. 
Now if we access https://{domain-name}/wso2am/devportal/ the portal appears fine. Now the login not working properly. 
If I try to login then it is redirected back to the above url. The console says 'No partial token found,redirecting to Anonymous View'. What should I do for this?